# kdb+/q: Check if argument has been supplied to the function call

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Say we have function `fun` with two arguments, second one is optional.
How to check within the function whether the second, optional argument has been supplied and act accordingly?

```
fun: {[x;optarg] $["optarg was supplied" like "optarg was supplied";"behavior 1"; "behavior 2"] }
fun[1;2] / behavior 1
fun[1]   / behavior 2
```

```

Comment: also, same question came up in the google group recently https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/personal-kdbplus/wj1b3l_u39E the conclusion was the same as jgleeson's below. You should join that group if you're not a member, same goes with the k4 listbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Supplying less than the specified number of arguments result in a [projection](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#64-projection).

A good alternative is to have your function accept one argument - a list. And then you can check for the existence of each element of the list.

```
f:{[l] $[1=count[l]; 
             / do something with first arg only; 
             / do something with both args ] 
}
```

Or you could have the function accept a dictionary (this allows you to set default values in the function).

```
q)f:{[dict] def:`a`b`c!10 20 30; 
            def:def upsert dict; 
            :def[`a] + def[`b] + def[`c] }


q)f[`a`b!5 10]
45

q)f[`a`c!5 10]
35
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't check for number of arguments, kdb+ will report `rank` error when number of arguments is more than expected. But there is a workaround which will result in function which will accept *any* number of arguments:

```
q)func:('[{$[1=count x;"one";"more"]};enlist])
q)func[1]
"one"
q)func[1;2]
"more"
q)func[1;2;3]
"more"
```

Here is an example:

```
q)func:('[{$[1=count x;x[0];sum x]};enlist])
q)func[1]
1
q)func[1;2]
3
q)func[1;2;4]
7
q)func[1;2;4;7]
14
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
func:('[{
         inputs:(`a_Required`b_Required`c_Optional`d_Optional);
         optionalDefaults:`c_Optional`d_Optional!(0b;1b);   
         if[(count inputs)<count x;-1"Too Many input arguments";:()];   
         data:inputs xcols optionalDefaults, (!) . (numInputs:count x)#'(inputs;x); 
         show data;
         data   
       };enlist]
     )
```